# Is it possible to keep a command sequence running after sending ctrl+c in the intermediate step?

Tags: bash, command-line, signals

I have a program, let is call it `xcommand`. when it is running, it has no stdout, but it writes its output to a file.

What I want to a achieve is like this: After I running `xcommand`, during its running I want to see its output in real time, and if I found something abnormal, I then turn off the output and at the same time, bring back `xcommand`.

I tried several ways, for example in the bash script I write

```
xcommand &
tail -f outputfile
fg
```

However, the problem is as soon as I press `ctrl+c`, the whole thing is stopped. And `fg` is not running at all.

So is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When non-interactive (like in scripts), shells don't do job control. They don't put asynchronous jobs in background. Those remain in the same process group as the rest of the script, so Ctrl-C will cause a SIGINT to be sent to them as well (assuming the script itself is started in foreground).

You can issue a `set -m` for the shell to do job control when non-interactive:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -m
xcommand & # start as a background job, so won't receive SIGINT upon ^C
tail -f outputfile # start in foreground. Will receive SIGINT.
fg # bring the xcommand job in foreground and wait for it. Will receive SIGINT
```

For that to work, that script has to be started in foreground. Also beware that if you press Ctrl-Z or if the background job tries to read from the terminal, you'll get into trouble.

In my experience, this kind of trick only *"works"* in `bash` or `yash`, generally not other Bourne-like shells.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your program in the background with

```
xcommand &
```

pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in the shell will *not* stop it.

If you then do

```
tail -f outputfile
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, only the `tail` process will be terminated.

If you then do

```
fg
```

you will put `xcommand` in the foreground.  Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will terminate the `xcommand` process.

So, don't put the `xcommand` process in the foreground, or, if you do, press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and follow up with `bg` to put it back into the background.

Comment: Hi, Kusalananda, I know if they run seprately, then it will work. But I want the whole process automatic. So actually I am running a script and  I found myself frequently forget to bring back the `xcommand` and start another run